# Citrix XenApp application not able to access Win7 - XPMode shared directory (access denied)

Tags: citrix, xenapp, windows

So many different layers, so much "fun"

I'm trying to do something I shouldn't be doing, but I don't have any other choice at this point.  We have old lab equipment with old software that will not run on Windows 7.  We've had an XP computer (10+ years old) connected to it and finally, the hard drive has died on us.  Corporate IT will not allow us to add a new XP computer to the network, so we've been forced to put a Win7 (64-bit) computer in its place and are running XP mode on it so we can run the software that operates the instrument.  This is all working wonderfully, no issues.

Now comes the tricky part.  The instrument software generates text files and we want our XenApp application to go and grab these text files and process them.  From my Win7 desktop computer, I have no trouble accessing the shared directory (full permissions to "Everyone") on the XP Mode virtual machine, but I can't access it from the Citrix app.

**EDIT**:
Found something else interesting.  I can do it by IP address without issue.  When I try to use the computer name, I receive the access denied message.  Using the computer name works for all other computers, but not with the XP-Mode virtual PC.

Win7 host computer name: mjkkfxy
xp-mode Virtual PC name: virtualxp-gc7

I can browse to \virtualxp-gc7 from any computer on the network, but the app can't access it.
The app can, however, access it with the IP address of the XP VPC: 10.26.60.196

The easy solution is to set up static IP address, but is there something I can do to make it work with the computer name?

Comment: You don't state what kind of problem you have when trying to access it. Not Found? Access Denied? Etc., etc.